# Dynamically created contents to be in the middle of webpage along with an automatic background

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I'm creating dynamic divisions based on back-end data. When I remove `float:left`
in jquery function, I'm able to get the subcontainer div automatically as background. But, it changes my layout. The dynamic divs will be upto 6. I don't want to hard code the height of subcontainer div. I need something like below images.

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls7hcdm1/1/)

[image: sample]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline-block; in main container.

try this:

```
.subcontainer {
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display:inline-block;; //add this line
}
```

Comment: This works great! (display:flex)But it did mess my layout.

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ls7hcdm1/3/ what is the issue with inline-block?

Comment: Not aligned in the middle. (The white background div is completely moved to left side). And yes it actually works other than the displacement of the subcontainer

Comment: As per fiddle its displaying proper. Check again